# Python Docx : Extract tables between two given strings

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to extract a specific list of tables that is found between two pieces of text in a word document. I am using python docx for this and the thing I am facing is that text can be parsed through using

```
document.paragraphs[index].text
```

while tables are parsed through using

```
document.tables[index].cell[row,col]
```

This separates the text and the tables making it harder to just have the list of tables contained between two pieces of text. The approach I am trying is to use the element of each list in the form below to obtain the address of the paragraph/table.

```
<docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph object at 0x04299FD0>
```

I would then extract each table's address and check whether it is between the starting and ending texts' addresses. BUT, the issue is that all the table addresses were larger than the start and ending addresses of the text and I could not find any documentation on how python docx finds those address because I assumed the address was sequential progressively through the document. Can this method work ? What other approach can I try to just look at those tables between two pieces of text in a word document ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround to this limitation described here:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40

You'll want to scroll down to the end and perhaps read in reverse order as well as the regular way; there have been some adjustments to the procedure based on changes to `python-docx` internals over recent versions.

The addresses that appear for objects like the one below, refer to memory locations and have no defined relationship to the order of paragraphs or other content in a python-docx document. They can be relied upon as a unique identifier for that Python in-memory object, but nothing more. Note the careful use of the term "memory object" as opposed to "document object". If two objects are created that both refer to the same paragraph in a document, for example, they will have two different addresses.

```
<docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph object at 0x04299FD0>
```

These values are accessible using the `id()` function in Python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id

Comment: Thanks ! After implementing the changes to the code in that link, I'm able to parse through the text and tables in order. I'm still curious though as to what those addresses are if they are not a specific position in the document.

Comment: @L2Code I've elaborated my response to address your secondary question.